# rescue_from not working in ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My class:

```
class TestUpdateJob < ActiveJob::Base

  include ActiveSupport::Rescuable
  rescue_from UserMediaException::UserNotFound, with: :destroy_user

  def self.call
    um = UserMedia.call('81274092340912873',100)
  end

  def destroy_user
    print "User to be destroyed"
  end


end
```

`UserMedia.call('81274092340912873',100)` raises `UserMediaException::UserNotFound` exception.

I'm trying to test `rescue_from`, but I'm not able to make it work. The message "User to be destroyed" never gets printed.

The custom exception that I'm rescuing (`UserMediaException::UserNotFound`) inherits from StandardError.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Try to start with `#perform` + `TestUpdateJob.perform_now` instead of `self.call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ActiveJobs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions) documentation, all jobs class must have their business logic in a `perform` instance method.

Your code should be :

```
class TestUpdateJob < ActiveJob::Base

  include ActiveSupport::Rescuable
  rescue_from UserMediaException::UserNotFound, with: :destroy_user

  def perform
    um = UserMedia.call('81274092340912873',100)
  end

  private

  def destroy_user
    print "User to be destroyed"
  end

end
```

After you can use your jobs with `perform_later` to enqueue it or `perform_now` to execute it directly :

```
TestUpdateJob.perform_later # Enqueue your job and execute it asynchronously
TestUpdateJob.perform_now # Execute your job now
```