# ActiveJob rescue_from returning success without raise and fail

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I'm trying to catch some errors in my `ApplicationJob`, but I don't want this errors to raise exceptions(and return failed job execution), but I want certain errors to be ignored(which basically returns success). 
I can accomplish this using regular `begin-rescue` in every job individually, but I want to share this rescues between multiple jobs.

The issue is that `rescue_from` catches the error but raises the error anyway, and the job fails on the execution.

application_job.rb

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base

  rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
    puts "Rescuing"
    true
  end

end
```

test_job.rb

```
class TestJob < ApplicationJob


  def perform(*args)
    raise ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound, "Wow"
  end

end
```

Log when I execute the job:

```
Performing TestJob (Job ID: fd58cbd5-eb03-4fdc-8301-1ea70a9b1d8b) from Async(default)
Error performing TestJob (Job ID: fd58cbd5-eb03-4fdc-8301-1ea70a9b1d8b) from Async(default) in 1.03ms: ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound (Failed.):
...
.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Rescuing
 => #<ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed.>
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is being raised? Based on your logs, it looks like your job is returning the exception object, not raising it

Answer (score -1):

This question is already some days old but has not been answered yet.

You have to `include ActiveSupport::Rescuable` in your job class before defining the rescues.

See also another question related to this topic: [rescue_from not working in ActiveJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900031/rescue-from-not-working-in-activejob)

Comment: This is not true. ActiveJob already includes `ActiveSupport::Rescuable` in the `ActiveJob::Base` class: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3de4aaff5e6440881c8a6056f87cff5dbc8b3ae4/activejob/lib/active_job/execution.rb#L9